# getting the data for datatables from a method

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using datatables to put the data fetched from server in a grid. below is the code I am using :-

```
function datatable()
    {
        $("#PartnerMsg").text('');
        $("#pardata").dataTable().fnClearTable();
        $("#pardata").dataTable().fnDestroy();
        var jobInfoTable = $('#pardata').dataTable({
            bPaginate: true,
            bAutoWidth: true,
            bProcessing: true,
            bFilter: false,
            bServerSide: false,
            paging:         true,
            //aaData: jsonObj.aaData,
            iTotalRecords: jsonObj.iTotalRecords,
            iTotalDisplayRecords: jsonObj.iTotalDisplayRecords,
            ajax: {
                sAjaxSource: LoadData,
            },
            aoColumns: [{ "mDataProp": "PartnerIdNumber" },
        { "mDataProp": "SubSegment" }]
        });
    }

    function LoadData(sEcho) {
        return my.vm.load(sEcho);
    }
```

But it is not working. I am trying to fetch the data from LoadData for datatables. Does anybody know how to make it work? It should call LoadData, pass parameter sEcho and take the data returned from LoadData and be able to put that in a grid.

Comment: What is `sEcho`?  You should also be calling a function like this `sAjaxSource: LoadData(sEcho)`

Comment: An unaltered copy of sEcho sent from the client side. This parameter will change with each draw (it is basically a draw count) - so it is important that this is implemented. Note that it strongly recommended for security reasons that you 'cast' this parameter to an integer in order to prevent Cross Site Scripting (XSS) attacks.